# gcc with parameters "-S -save-temps" puts intermediate files in current directory

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

The parameters `-S -save-temps` work fine, as long as i don't use them on files with the same name.

Think of the following situation: I have a project with a main directory and a subdirectory with the name `subDir` and in both of the directories are files placed with the name `file.c`. If I now call `gcc -S -save-temps file.cpp subDir/file.c` only one intermediate file with the name `file.i` will be generated.

That is the expected behaviour, as the man file of `gcc` tells me, that the intermediate files will always be placed in the current path, when using `-save-temps`.

My problem is, that I'm working on projects I don't know in advance. It could very well be, that someone constructed the above mentioned example in his Makefiles. In that case I would be stuck, because I need both intermediate files.

A few words to the system I'm constructing (for better understanding): My tool uses `make --just-print` to collect the calls, a make file of a project invokes. I scan these calls for compiler calls and add the `-save-temps` and `-S` options. The purpose is to get every preprocessed file, that is used in the process of compiling the project.

Do you have any ideas, how I'm able to get every preprocessed file, even if the above mentioned example should appear?

Comment: How would this change if we were to use the clang++ compiler because the -save and -temps are unrecognisable by the terminal?

Comment: This is resolved using `man clang++` which suggests we can use `-E` for printing out the `.ii` file which results after macro expansion and other preprocessing and `-S` for saving the compiled code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem with file.cpp / file.c in different directories. GCC will create a `*.ii` and a `*.i` depending on the files' extension.

If they both have c||cpp you can use `-E` and receive only one `*.i` where you can search for the pragma `# 1 "<FILE_PATH>"` and extract it via a script.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my post. Both files in my example have the same extension.

Comment: Yes, I know the parameter -E. But the problem is, that there are more than one lines of the pattern # 1 "<FILE_PATH>".

Well, until one minute ago, I thought, this would be a problem. But I think every other line with this pattern either just declares a path or includes a header file with the ending .h. So it should really be possible to parse that stuff. But I'm not sure yet, if I can count on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the help of http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output I should be able to parse the files I get by using `-E`.

Answer (score 16):

In gcc 4.5 you can use the option `-save-temps=obj` when using the `-o` option. This saves the intermediate files in the same directory as the output file, which can help prevent issues when you have the same filename using different source and output directories.

```bash
gcc -save-temps=obj -c dir1/foo.c -o dir1/foo.o
gcc -save-temps=obj -c dir2/foo.c -o dir2/foo.o
```

The intermediate files will be saved as `dir1/foo.*` and `dir2/foo.*`